# Clang linking with a .so file

Tags: c++, linker, clang, chaiscript

I keep getting

```
ld: library not found for -lchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1.so
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When trying to link to a *.so* file.

I'm using this command:

```
clang++ Main.cpp -o foo -L./ -lchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1.so
```

What am I doing wrong?

File *libchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1.so* is in the same directory as file *Main.cpp*. I thought the `-L./` would add the *.so* to the library search paths.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, the `-L` option adds the search path, but the linker adds the `.so` (or `.a`) suffix itself (just like it adds the `lib` prefix). So you only need to have `-lchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1` and the linker will find it.

You can also skip the adding of the path, and link directly with the file:

```
clang++ Main.cpp -o foo libchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1.so
```

---

Note that the runtime linker (which is what actually loads the shared libraries when you run your program) might not be able to find the library if it's not in the runtime linker's path. You can tell the (compile time) linker to add a path to the shared-library path in the generated program though:

```
clang++ Main.cpp -o foo libchaiscript_stdlib-5.3.1.so -Wl,-rpath,/absolute/path
```

The `-Wl` option tells the compiler front-end to pass an option to the linker, and the linker option `-rpath` adds a path to the runtime-linker search path.

Comment: What's the difference between `-L` and `-rpath`? Seems to me that both are used to specify library paths.

Comment: @Searene `-L` adds to the build-time linker path. `-rpath` adds to the load-time library path (when the OS loads the library).

Comment: I saw your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176747/how-to-use-a-library-with-headers-and-so-files Clang and GCC receive the same arguments?

Comment: @ThiagoLagesdeAlencar Yes, GCC and Clang are mostly compatible and use many of the same arguments. Details might differ, like what optimizations are enabled by the `-O` flag and its variants, but the flags themselves are mostly the same.