# How to use a library with headers and .so files?

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to C and wanted to use a library ([MLT Multimedia Framework](http://www.mltframework.org/))

I've built it and it produced the following directories: `include`  `lib`  `share`

Inside `lib` there are `.so` `.a` `.la` files
Inside `include` there are `.h` files

Now, I'm instructed to do this:

`#include <framework/mlt.h>` which is inside `include/mlt/framework/`

### Questions:

- Why I do I need to place the header file that contains only function prototypes? Where are the real functions then? are they linked someway to the ones included in `lib` directory?
- Where to place my own files and **how to compile it**?
- How to learn more about the topics:

  - Dynamic/Static libraries
  - Building / making / installing
  - How to use any C library

Comment: To give specific instructions: What IDE/compiler/etc. you´re using? Pure GCC? Some graphical IDE? Makefiles?

Comment: What is the relation to C++? Using C++ libraries in C is between tricky and impossible.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Because in C++ one have to use C libraries.

Comment: No, @Hi-Angel. What makes you think so? Even if you had to use C libs from C++, that wouldn't imply the other direction.

Comment: @Hi-Angel C++ libs are possible (but not very compatible to other platforms/toolchains/etc). And UlrichEckhardt did mean something else in the first place: You can´t use C++ libs in C

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt well, because every library that one have to use in C or C++ have no mangled names, and hence C? ☺

Comment: @deviantfan I saw, but they asked what is the relation to C++, so one have to answer, that at least the vice versa thing is possible.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear: Why does this stackoverflow question have a C++ tag? Judging from the content of the text, it shouldn't have one. Since I didn't rule out any not yet revealed relation to the question, I asked what the "relation to C++" is.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it have *the same* relation to C++ as to C. So it would be absolutely equal questions «What have this to do with C++» and «What have this to do with C».

Comment: @Hi-Angel OP mentions that it is a C lib. and that he/she is new to C (ie. apparently the whole program is in C). That´s why the C++ tag is questionable.

Comment: @deviantfan ah, well, perhaps it is… It's just that the questions they marked with bullets have the same answers for C and C++.

Comment: @deviantfan by the way, instead of «he/she» you can say «they». It is perfectly fine to refer to a single person with the pronoun.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Sorry for nitpicking, but there are differences. Eg `extern "C" {}` etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't have the function prototypes, how would the compiler know what functions exist in the library? Short answer is: It doesn't. Longer answer: The compiler doesn't care about library files, static (files ending in `.a`) or shared (files ending in `.so`), all it cares about is the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). It's up to the linker to handle resolving undefined references.

When you use libraries, you include the header files that contain the needed *declarations* (structures, classes, types, function prototypes) into the source file. The source file plus all included header files forms the translation unit that the compiler uses to generate code. If there are undefined references (for example a call to a function in the library) the compiler adds special information about that to the generated *object file*. The linker then looks through all object files, and if it finds an unresolved reference it tries to find it in the other object files and the provided libraries. If all definitions are resolved the linker generates the final executable, otherwise it will report the unresolved definitions as errors.

---

To answer your other questions:

> Where to place my own files and how to compile it?

This is two questions, the answer to the first one (about placement of your files) is that it doesn't really matter. For small project with only a few source and header files, it's common to place all files in a common project directory.

The second question, about compiling, there are different ways to do it too. If there are only one or two source files you could use the compiler frontend (e.g. `gcc`) to compile and *link* and generate your executable all in one go:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g source1.c source2.c -o your_program_name
```

The above command takes two source files, compiles and links them into the program `your_program_name`.

If you need to use a library, there are one or two things that you need to add to the above command line:

1. You need to tell the linker to link with the library, this is done with e.g. the `-l` (lower case L) option:

   ```
   $ gcc -Wall -g source1.c source2.c -o your_program_name -lthe_library
   ```

   It's important to note that `the_library` is the base name of the library. If the library file is named `libthe_library.so` then only `the_library` part is needed, the linker will add the other parts automatically.
2. If the library is not in a standard location, then you need to tell the compiler and linker where the library file are. This is done with the `-I` (capital i) option to tell the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) where the header files are, and the `-L` (capital l) where the linker files are.

   Something like

   ```
   $ gcc -Wall -g -Ilocation/of/headers source1.c source2.c -o your_program_name -Llocation/of/libraries -lthe_library
   ```

If you have more than a couple of source files, it's common to use so called [makefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) that lists all source files, their dependencies, compiler and linker flags, and contain rules on how to build object files and link the final program. Such a makefile could look like

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -g

SOURCES = source1.c source2.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

TARGET  = your_program_name

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
```

The above makefile should do just about the same as the previous command line. The big difference is that it's much easier to add more source files, add special rules for special files, and most importantly, the `make` program will handle dependencies so that if one source file haven't been modified since last build then it won't be compiled. The last bit will make big projects with many source files build much quicker when only one or a few source files has been modified.

---

> How to learn more about the topics [...]

By going to your favorite search engine, and looking for those topics there. I also recommend e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/).

---

Of course, if you use an [Integrated Development Environment (a.k.a. an IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) then you don't have to compile from the command line, or to make your own makefiles, the IDE will handle all that for you. It will also have dialogs for the project settings where you can enter include paths and library paths, and what libraries to link with.

Comment: Huh? this is an AMAZING answer! a piece of cake.
Thank you for taking the time to explain this .. Please, write a book!

Comment: This answer is indeed amazing! Note for myself: It's also accept `-l:libthe_library.so` and I had to add `-Wl,-Rlocation/of/libraries`

Answer (score 5):

> Why I do I need to place the header file that contains only function prototypes?

So as to satisfy your compiler for declaration of those functions or declaration of classes. As C++ is static type checking language, they must know the type of objects which they will be using.

> Where to place my own files and how to compile it?

You can place you code anywhere in you filesystem; only make sure to include .h files in includes path and lib while compiling. Usually you need to modify your path.

You can check about building on this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system

Comment: Ok but where are the real functions if I just supplied the headers?

Comment: They will be implemented in shared objects (.so) files or static libraries (.a) files . you can check lib folder for these files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `README` file that came with the code.  It should tell you how to install it into the system properly.  Usually there is an `install` build target which installs the resulting files into the proper directories.

The usual sequence of commands to build and install most products is:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```