# Force g++/clang++ to use local `libstdc++.so`

Tags: c++, g++, ld, clang++

I am trying to compile a library using a specific version of `libstdc++.so`, not the system one.

The compilation script uses `waf`.

I tried to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path/to/directory/of/my/libstdc++.so>`.
Since I use fish, I have also tried with `set --export LD_LIBRARY_PATH <path/to/directory/of/my/libstdc++.so>` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path/to/directory/of/my/libstdc++.so> waf`

However, until now it still links against the system `libstdc++.so`

Anyone knows how to force the usage of my `libstdc++.so`?

Comment: Use the `-L` compiler/linker flag.

Comment: `-L` doesn't work for me

Comment: What doesn't work? Show your exact command and error messages.

Comment: It works, but when trying to load it using the specific `libstdc++.so` (in my case the Julia's one) it fails, saying `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found`

Comment: This probably means your version is too old and/or you are compiling against new version headers and linking against an old binary library. Please [edit] your question and add exact, complete and unedited build commands and error messages you are getting, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the standard library in clang using the `-stdlib=<yours>` flag. See here for more info: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html

EDIT: Leaving my past answer up there just so that it's a known edit, but you should be able to just use `-nostdlib` and optionally, `-nostdinc`, to compile your program. Then to supply your own standard library, just add it as a compiler argument. For example:

```sh
clang -nostdinc -nostdlib -I/custom/include/path foo.c /path/to/your/cstdlib.so
```

For more help configuring the linker, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160245/clang-linking-with-a-so-file).